# Models for common entities, ideally for JPA

Tags: database, database-design, jpa

Is there a good resource for finding models for common/standard entities? What I mean is typically I want to define a number of entities in my database such as address, company, etc... Now I need to think what fields are required, what type, what size, etc... When thousands of people have had the same problem in the past and solved it. Therefore I am pretty convinced I can find off the shelf models (ideally JPA entities) somewhere. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder why it got two -1? I don't thing there is anything wrong with reusing templates or models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Database Answers http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/ for conceptual models of subject matters that I'm not familiar with.

I don't think the models you see there are in the form you are looking for.  But they will show you the entities, relationships and attributes that databaseanswers thinks are relevant.  From there, you can build your own model in the form that suits you.

Comment: yep this is pretty good. Thanks. What would be even better is a jpa together with the validation rules etc... but this is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition, erdiagrams.com might be a good resource/starting point as well:
http://www.erdiagrams.com
Most "standard", common entities are mentioned there. Also, the Data Model Resource Book might help: universal data models.